# Авторизация по почте или номеру телефона

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-3, .net-6

Стоит задача, реализовать авторизацию по почте или номеру телефона. Использую ASP.NET 6.0 + Identity.
Необходимо правильно провалидировать логин (это почта или номер телефона). Вопрос именно по архитектурной части. Сейчас это работает на if else. Что то типо такого:

```
if(isEmail(username))
{
 // Логика для создания пользователя с Email = login и отправки кода
} 
else 
{
  // Логика для создания пользователя с PhoneNumber= login и отправки кода
  ....
}
```

Затем та же логика при подтверждении кода.
Хочется найти красивое, и в первую очередь правильное архитектурное решение.
Прошу натолкнуть на грамотную мысль.)

Comment: Как по мне, так надо не угадывать на бэке, что там прилетело, а с фронта данные отправлять уже в нужном виде.

Comment: Да, они уже провалидированы на фронте, просто хотелось бы перестраховаться. Но возможно это лишнее...

Comment: Смысл не в валидации, а в том что знать, что перед вами точно почта или точно телефон, почту валидировать как почту, телефон как телефон, бэк не должен определять это автоматом.

Comment: ну вас не смущает, что у вас поле под названием username будет содержать номер телефона? А если я хочу, чтобы у меня был ник чисто из цифр? Разделяйте всегда разные данные, делайте второе поле или вообще второй метод для обработки входа по номеру.